# Enqueue and play a folder of .mp3s in Windows Media Player with Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows-media-player

Is it possible to play all the .mp3's within a folder in windows media player?

I am using Python 3.2, and so far I have code that returns the absolute location of a random album in my music folder. 
I would like to take that string and somehow open WMP and play the music within that folder

Any suggestions?

For reference, here is my code:

```
import random
import os

path = ["Q:\\#User\\Music\\", "Q:\\#user\\What CDs\\"]
print("You shall play " + random.sample(list(filter(lambda f: len([i for i in f if i in "."]) == 0, sum(map(lambda d: list(map(lambda e: d + "\\" + e,os.listdir(d))),list(filter(lambda c: len([i for i in c if i in "."]) == 0, sum(map(lambda a: list(map(lambda b: a + b ,os.listdir(a))), path), [])))), []) )), 1)[0])


input()
```

And yes, ideally that wouldn't all be in one line. I was learning how to use `map` and `lambda` and thought I'd challenge myself. 
I'd now like to take this one step further, and play the random album.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmmmm, interesting idea.

I would probably create a .m3u file on the fly and then pass it to WMP as a command line argument (which, according to [WMP Command Line](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd562624%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) is certainly doable).

A .m3u file is simply a text file. Here is an example .m3u for the Tool album Undertow:

```
#EXTM3U
#EXTINF:295,Tool - Intolerance
01 - Intolerance.mp3
#EXTINF:296,Tool - Prison Sex
02 - Prison Sex.mp3
#EXTINF:307,Tool - Sober
03 - Sober.mp3
#EXTINF:434,Tool - Bottom
04 - Bottom.mp3
#EXTINF:330,Tool - Crawl Away
05 - Crawl Away.mp3
#EXTINF:332,Tool - Swamp Song
06 - Swamp Song.mp3
#EXTINF:322,Tool - Undertow
07 - Undertow.mp3
#EXTINF:363,Tool - 4°
08 - 4°.mp3
#EXTINF:466,Tool - Flood
09 - Flood.mp3
#EXTINF:947,Tool - Disgustipated
69 - Disgustipated.mp3
```

Good luck!

PS - You can invoke the command line argument by importing the `os` module and using `os.system("YOUR DOS COMMAND")`

Oh, and the format used in an m3u file:

```
#EXTINF:<song-time-in-seconds>, <Artist> - <Song>
<Track_Num> - <File name>
```

If it wasn't clear.

Comment: You can also delete the .m3u file immediately after WMP opens. WMP reads everything from the file when it first opens.